# PHP batch processing

Tags: php, linux, symfony, exec, batch-processing

I am building an social media application where a user is required to post something and this posted content is then propogated to all the members within his/her 4 circles. Meaning the query goes into a loop. Its like a family tree. The logic works perfectly fine. But now when number of members in each circle keep growing, the the exceution is exceeding the max execution time which is currently set to 90 and which is fairly good enough.

We dont want to increase the time limit as this is not a permanently solution. So, we have though about implmenting this using bath processing concept. Like a user posts something on the web, and then the id and text is handed over to the batch script. The response is generated imediatly to the web user and the batch script continues to work behind the scene.

Any idea or though on how this can be implemented. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does it take 90+ seconds? Have you profiled your code? This is waaay too abstract to answer. Show, don't tell.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a Relational DB for this (like mysql). In my experience, while it can work, it is surely not the best tool to model social interactions because it is not scalable/efficient.

You should probably explore a NoSQL database with graph support for this kind of problem, like OrientDB http://orientdb.com/orientdb/ .

Not exactly what you suggested but I think it will save you from many headache in the end.

Comment: Hi Diego, Thanks for your quick response. We have tried using Neo4j DB, but then realised we are way far ahead of making any base core changes to the application. That is the reason we are now trying to find an alternative solution which can fit into, without modifying any core logic or architecture.

Comment: I'm happy that my answer triggered research on your part, but I understand that it can be frustrating to port your architecture on a different model architecture. Anyway be advised that the complexity of query joins on the same table is pretty bad in terms of performance ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is named a [Message queuing service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queuing_service).

Basicly, in your app you send a message saying for exemple to dispatch the content to members of circles of the current user. Then this message will be consumed asynchronously by a consumer (an other running PHP instance of your app that is able to handle those messages)

Have a look at RabbitMQ or Beanstalkd, with PHP.

Comment: Hi Yassine, thanks for your quick response. I will have a look at your options.